# Scala, cryptic compiler error: found: Result[_ >: Some[String] with Option[T] <: Option[Any]] required: Result[Option[T]]

Tags: scala

This code (https://ideone.com/6y81ZT)

```
object Main extends App {

    import scala.util.Try

    case class Result[T](value :T)

    def hi() = "hi"

    def safer[T](f : () => T) : Try[Result[Option[T]]] = {
        Try(hi)
            .map((r) => Result(Some(r)))
            .orElse(Try(Result(None)))
    }

    safer(hi)

}
```

Produces compilation error:

```
Main.scala:12: error: type mismatch;  found   :
scala.util.Try[Main.Result[_ >: Some[String] with Option[T] <: Option[Any]]]
required: scala.util.Try[Main.Result[Option[T]]]
```

How should this message be understood ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple problems.

First, you passing `hi` to `Try.apply`, which is causing it to be nailed down to `Try[String]` instead of `Try[T]`.

The second error comes from `Result(Some(r))`, where the compiler is expecting `Result[Option[T]]`. The type inside the lambda is prematurely nailed down to `Result[Some[T]]`, which causes the `orElse` infer the weird compound type.

```
Try(f())
    .map(r => Result(Option(r))) // Try[Result[Some[T]]]
    .orElse(Try(Result(None)))   // Try[Result[None]]
```

It also happens when (note the inferred type):

```
scala> Try(1).map(r => Result(Some(r))).orElse(Try(Result(None)))
res6: scala.util.Try[Result[_ >: Some[Int] with None.type <: Option[Int]]] = Success(Result(Some(1)))
```

The above wouldn't happen if `Result` were covariant over `T` (notice the desired type being inferred):

```
case class Result[+T](value: T)

scala> Try(1).map(r => Result(Some(r))).orElse(Try(Result(None)))
res7: scala.util.Try[Result[Option[Int]]] = Success(Result(Some(1)))
```

Without changing `Result`, this works:

```
def safer[T](f: () => T) : Try[Result[Option[T]]] = {
    Try(f())
        .map(r => Result(Option(r)))
        .orElse(Try(Result(None)))
}
```

It's not really necessary to keep the outer `Try` in the return type, as you will never actually return a failure. (It is always recovered by `Result(None)`.

You *could* simplify the code it you did that:

```
def safer[T](f: () => T) : Result[Option[T]] = Result(Try(f()).toOption)
```